# how to increment all digits in string(Bash Script)

Tags: bash, awk

My code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Zadaj vetu: "
read str
echo $str | awk '{ for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf("%s ",$i); print $1; }' | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d '#' | tr -d '=' | tr -d '-'
```

I need help, I don't understand how to make all the digits in the string that we thought to increase by one. (If there are 9 we should do 0)

example: `He11o my name 3s Artem 2029` --> `He22o my name 4s Artem 3130`

Comment: The `for` loop is processing each field, not each character.

Comment: What is the `tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d '#' | tr -d '=' | tr -d '-'` for?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `tr` command for this.

```
echo "$str" | tr '0-9' '1-90' | tr -d '#='
```

Each character in the first argument is mapped to the corresponding character in the second argument. And it automatically expands ranges of characters, so this is short for `tr 012456789 1234567890`

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
echo 'He11o my name 3s Artem 2029' | perl -pe 's/([0-9])/($1 + 1) % 10/ge'
```

- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMNT/` is substitution;
- the `/g` makes "global", it replaces all occurrences;
- the `/e` interprets the replacement as code and runs it;
- the `%` is the modulo operator, it will make 0 from 10.

Comment: thank you very much, the program has finally worked properly.